# making sbt scala build file bring in apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I have a scala build file under my `project` directory like follows, but my imports fail, what is the idiomatic way to solve this? are scala build files still the recommended build as opposed to build.sbt definitions? the official documentation doesn't offer any insights.

```
import sbt.{Def, ExclusionRule, ModuleID}
import sbt.Keys.{dependencyOverrides, libraryDependencies}
import sbt._

object MyBuild {

  lazy val sparkVersion = "2.2.1"

  val commonDependencies: Seq[ModuleID] = Seq()

  val sparkDependencies: Seq[ModuleID] = Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
    "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % sparkVersion sparkVersion,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion,
    "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.7.2"
  )

  lazy val project = Project("my-project", file("."))
    .settings(
      libraryDependencies ++= sparkDependencies
    )
}
```

In my source code I can't:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

What's the simple solution? Do I need to specify that my object herein should be executed or does that just happen by default?

*build.properties*:

```
sbt.version = 0.13.16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to make the following change to your Build definition

```
object MyBuild extends Build {
  ....
}
```

To avoid these kind of common issues, try moving to `build.sbt` approach of using build definitions in SBT, unless you've a lot of customizations in your build spec.

Comment: I solved it Indeed by adding a `build.sbt` file referencing the dependencies declaratively. Will try this approach next time.